# Reversing a LinkedList?

Tags: java

The code works as it was handed to me by my lecturer, I wont see him for 4ish weeks I have no one to go to for this.
I need to understand how this works, well a section of the code.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Reverse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinkedList<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
    names.add("Ceri");
    names.add("Jesus");
    names.add("Abigail");

    Reverse(names);
}

public static void Reverse(LinkedList<String> list){

    System.out.println("->" + list);

    if(list.size() > 1){
        String s = list.removeLast();
        Reverse(list);
        list.addFirst(s);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}

This bit to be precise:

```
   if(list.size() > 1){
        String s = list.removeLast();
        Reverse(list);
        list.addFirst(s);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

I went into debug mode to see which lines were executed and the `list.addFirst(s)` only executes when `list.size() > 1` is false even though its in the for block.
Also it loops through twice assigning *s* "Abigail" and "Jesus" to *s* but when `list.addFirst(s)` is run, its as if *s* acts like an array?

Very hard to explain what I mean, if you run this through eclipse and debug mode you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a recursive function. The `list.size()` check is needed because you need a base case for recursive functions. It ensures that if there is only one item in the list, then don't do anything with it.

Basically, it starts like this

```
Ceri, Jesus, Abigail
```

When the Reverse function is called, it sees that there are 3 items, so it stores Abigail in S (let's call this S1) Note that the function isn't finished yet, and it will call Reverse again.

You have the list `Ceri, Jesus`, and your S1 is `Abigail`. Reverse is called here, and S (lets call it S2) is now `Jesus`. This function is also not finished yet, since it has to call Reverse.

The list is now only `Ceri`, so when it's called, it stops (only 1 item). Going back up the function calls, (from most recently called first) you see that S2 gets added to the front of the list, so now the list looks like

```
Jesus, Ceri
```

Then, add S1.

`Abigail, Jesus, Ceri`. Voila! Reversed list!

Comment: 'Function calls', that literally done it for it, it clicked as soon as I read that!

Answer (score 0):

The essence of this algorithm is recursive. It states (and makes it happen) that the reverse of a list is:

```
If the list is longer than 1 entry (a 1-entry list is its own reverse)
1. Remove the last entry.
2. Reverse the remaining list.
3. Add the removed item onto the start of the list.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Reverse` method is recursive (it invokes itself), and that seems to be confusing you.  Given your specific starting list, the method will recurse twice, for a total of three invocations, each with its own, separate set of local variables.  The `list` argument is passed at each recursion, though, so although each invocation has its own copy of that variable, they all reference the same object.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

- Initial call

  - `list.size()` is initially 3.
  - Element `"Abigail"` is removed and held in local variable `s` (of this stack frame)
  - First recursion

    - `list.size()` is initially 2, one element having already been removed
    - Element `"Jesus"` is removed and held in local variable `s` of *this* stack frame; this is not the same variable as in the initial call's frame
    - Second recursion

      - `list.size()` is initially 1, one element having been removed by each of the previous `Reverse()` invocations (neither of which has yet returned)
      - the list is not modified.  `"Ceri"` is its only element at this point.
    - The second recursion returns
    - This frame's `s` (`"Jesus"`) is added to the front of the list to yield (`"Jesus"`, `"Ceri"`)
  - The first recursion returns
  - This frame's `s` (`"Abigail"`) is added to the front of the list to yield (`"Abigail"`, `"Jesus"`, `"Ceri"`)